# how to ask for new value before showing to the user?

Tags: fiddler

I found this sample code where i can replace something automatically in the page

```
// If content-type is HTML, then remove all DIV tags
if (oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "html")){
  // Remove any compression or chunking
  oSession.utilDecodeResponse();

  var oBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oSession.responseBodyBytes);

  // Replace all instances of the DIV tag with an empty string
  var oRegEx = /<div[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div>/gi;
  oBody = oBody.replace(oRegEx, "");

  // Set the response body to the div-less string
  oSession.utilSetResponseBody(oBody);
}
```

But how can i ask for the new value, instead of replacing it automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you

```
if (oSession.uriContains("/yoururl/here")) {
    oSession.utilDecodeResponse();
    var oBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oSession.responseBodyBytes);
    var oRegEx = /this text will be replaced everywhere/gi;
    var mydefaulttext = 'new text';
    var mymsgbox = FiddlerScript.prompt('Lets change something', mydefaulttext);
    oBody = oBody.replace(oRegEx, mymsgbox);
    oSession.utilSetResponseBody(oBody);
}
```

OnBeforeResponse